# Android saving a docx file

Tags: android, file-io, fonts

I want to save text from my app that can be opened from various devices (phones, tablets, computers, ect) and after doing research I figured a docx would be the best choice. I need to have the text be monospaced so a simple .txt file would not work. I noticed though that when I save this file and try to open it up using QuickOffice or POLARIS or any other office type application on my phone or tablet I get a message "Unsupported file". I can open it in office using my computer but I get a message saying that I need to select an encoding. Is there a way in my program either by setting the `fontFamily` or something similar to remedy this?

I'm under the assumption that it is saving using whatever the default font is for Android and that font doesn't exist in these other applications so it does not recognize it. But I could be wrong. Any help would be appreciated! This is my code for saving: (I should note that string1(2)(3) come from a `TextView`

```
private void saveResults() {

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMddHHmmss", Locale.getDefault());
    String timeStamp = format.format(new Date());
    String filename = timeStamp + "_Results.docx";
    CharSequence fileOutput = "Results:\n" + string1 + "\n" + string2 + "\n\n" +
                        string3;

    if(isExternalStorageWritable()){

        try{
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                    new OutputStreamWriter(fileOut);
            myOutWriter.append(fileOutput);
            myOutWriter.close();
            fileOut.close();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Saved " + filename + " to " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cannot write to external storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you creating the DOCX?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question with my code :)

Comment: That doesn't look like docx format at all.  That's why you're having problems.

Comment: I didn't know docx had a specific format. After a quick search I found something about Office Open XML. Is that how it needs to be formatted?

Comment: Every file type has a specific format.  Even .txt has a specific format-  ascii characters 1 byte per character starting at index 0.  Do anything else (like use unicode) and a lot of programs won't read it correctly.  DOCX is the MS Word format for newer versions of word, and yes it is also called OOXML.  The specification of OOXML is several hundred pages long, generally you use a library to write it.  Or avoid it.

Comment: Also, what you want is probably better done with .rtf (rich text format).  Its a far simpler format, is supported by many more apps, and is easier to use.

Comment: I actually have tried to use .rtf but I got the same result, is there documentation on how to format an .rtf file so that it can be opened?